# ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version: '3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) \n[GCC 7.2.0]'

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, redhat

My OS is Linux server Redhat. I worked with Python 3.6.6 and Anaconda3 which had Python 3.6.5. My problem was started when I deleted Desktop by mistake. After that, I had to install Python again, but I removed Anaconda3 completely. Now my project is built correctly. But when I run it, I get this error:

ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version: '3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) \n[GCC 7.2.0]'

I have checked all solution in Stackoverflow, but my error have not been removed.

Would you please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved when I update cx_Freeze.